# Turn off batch processing in Kettle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, batch-processing, pentaho, kettle

I am running a Pentaho Kettle transformation to insert into and update an Oracle 11g database that Kettle connects to using ODBC. When I run the transformation (or edit any of the database steps) I get the following message:

> WARNING: Error handling in combination with batch processing is not fully supported on the used database because of driver limitations. Proceed with caution at your own risk.

Since I don't want to proceed if caution is needed, and I can't change the drivers I figure I better turn of the batch processing. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using table output transformation?

Comment: Yes, I am using table output, as well as insert / update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tickbox in the step configuration "Use batch mode". If you don't see the tickbox on the particular step, then it's not relevant.

However why are you using ODBC?  The batch mode works fine with the jdbc driver with oracle.  Generally the batch mode is only an issue for MySQL, and only with specific driver versions (which is why its a warning)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There is a checkbox, but it is greyed out and unchecked. I would guess that means that batch mode is disabled, but then why do I get the warning? I am using ODBC because I could not get the JDBC to work, perhaps I should just ask a question about that...

Comment: Yes agreed the warning is perhaps overkill. Perhaps it should say something cleverer about why it has disabled the checkbox.

Comment: The "Proceed with caution at your own risk." makes me believe that I am using batch mode, but apparently I am not?

Comment: Try deleting the table output transformation and adding it again.